# How to upload a file on Google Drive with name of the file using apex

Tags: google-drive-api, salesforce, integration, apex, apex-code

**When am I uploading a file using this then file will uploaded but file name is not uploade please help me to out to solve this problem..**

**Help me how to send metadata with this**

````
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setMethod('POST'); //method call
req1.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media');
req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token); //provide authentication code
req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
//req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
req1.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueof(contentSize));
req1.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
req1.setBodyAsBlob(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64));
httpResponse res  = new httpResponse();
system.debug('res>>>>>'+res);
res = http.send(req1);
integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
string resBody  = res.getBody();
req1.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
HttpResponse resp1 = http.send(req1);
System.debug(resp1.getBody());
system.debug('statusCode>>>>>  '+statusCode);
system.debug('resBody>>>..' + resBody);```
````

Comment: Where are you setting the file metadata for the body?

Comment: the salesforce "apex" and "oracle APEX" are 2 completely different products. Please put the correct tags

Comment: @DaImTo I am not understanding how to send metadata with this..

Comment: Have you checked the docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: @DaImTo Yes,I have already checked this docs but unable to get the exact way to send the metadata, i have tried to send methdata in request body still I am getting the same issue ..files are upload with untitle on google drive

Comment: They are untitled because you are not setting the metadata.  From the docs **Metadata. The metadata must come first and must have a Content-Type header set to application/json; charset=UTF-8. Add the file's metadata in JSON format.
Media. The media must come second and must have a Content-Type header of any MIME type. Add the file's data to the media part.**